# Rewrite an OpenERP 7 method to Odoo 8 syntax?

Tags: syntax, odoo-8, openerp-7

I have the following OpenERP 7 method:

```
#   Function to get the vat number (CIF/NIF) and then show it on invoice form view
def _get_vat_num(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args=None, context=None):
    partner_pool = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    invoice_pool = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    res = {}
    for inv in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        invoice = invoice_pool.browse(cr,uid, inv.id, context=None)
        partner = partner_pool.browse(cr, uid, invoice.partner_id.id, context=None)
        res[inv.id] = partner.vat

    return res

inv_vat = fields.Char(compute='_get_vat_num', string="CIF/NIF")
```

I need to rewrite it to Odoo v8 syntax. I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
def _get_vat_num(self):
    partner_pool = self.env['res.partner']
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']

    res = {}
    for inv in self.browse(self.id):
        invoice = invoice_pool.browse(inv.id)
        partner = partner_pool.browse(invoice.partner_id.id)
        res[inv.id] = partner.vat

    return res
```

What should be the correct code?

Comment: What is your function for?  What error are you getting?

Comment: How to call that function in your py side ? depends on calling we must need to add the different decorator in odoo v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting a functional field.  You should instead be able to define the field as a [related field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) like so:

```
inv_vat = fields.Char(string="VAT", related="partner_id.vat")
```

If you really want it as a functional field, this is how you would do it

```
inv_vat = fields.Char(string="VAT", compute="_get_vat_num")

def _get_vat_num(self):
    # self is a recordset of account.invoice records
    for invoice in self:
        # to set a functional field, you just assign it
        invoice.inv_vat = invoice.partner_id.vat
```

Check out the recordset documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#recordsets

And the computed fields documentation:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields

Comment: Thanks @alexbclay. I am not trying to store this field because it's only for additional reference for some people. For this reason I have created a computed field `inv_vat = fields.Char(compute='_get_vat_num', string="CIF/NIF")`. My problem is to rewrite the function. I go to try your solution.

Comment: I tried with related field with `store=False` and it works! Thanks for the example function, it was very useful too.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!